# Rails Engine configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails Engine that handles the OAuth mechanism with a third party. I would like to have all the configuration in a Struct attribute, so all the engine config data is stored together:

```
require 'rails'


module ThirdParty
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

    initializer "third-party.some_init_task" do |app|
      ThirdPartyConfig = Struct.new(:uri, :client_id, :client_secret, :redirect_uri)

      app.config.thirdparty = ThirdPartyConfig.new
      app.config.thirdparty.uri = "https://thirdparty.com"
      app.config.thirdparty.client_id = ""
      app.config.thirdparty.client_secret = ""
      app.config.thirdparty.redirect_uri = ""
    end
  end
end
```

Some of the configuration should be defined in the application level initializers:

```
class Application < Rails::Application

    config.thirdparty.client_id = <valid_client_id>
    config.thirdparty.client_secret = <valid_client_secret>
    config.thirdparty.redirect_uri = <redirect_uri>
end
```

But as config.thirdparty still is undefined while loading the application initializer, it fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying the load order for the initializer in your engine.  You should be able to force it to load before the application configuration runs.  Here is a guess at the point you want to load your initializer

```
initializer "third-party.some_init_task", :before=> :load_config_initializers do |app|
```

If that does not work, try loading it before another initializer.

Comment: Thanks @cowboycoded!! I've changed the application config data to an initializer instead of writing it in application.rb. Also I've set a valid value for the :before parameter in the Rails Engine as you suggested. Really worthy your help!!!

Comment: @juandebravo what value did you give to the `:before` entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure rails engine through host/main application

[Initializing object within devolopment.rb envirorment using gem within rails mountable engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025931/initializing-object-within-devolopment-rb-envirorment-using-gem-within-rails-mou/35111299#35111299)

Comment: You've got an answer that solves another problem - great! It might help people looking at other questions - also great! What you should do, then, is ask yourself if the _questions_ are duplicates. If so, flag them as such. If they aren't duplicates, maybe you can tailor your other answer to specifically answer this question. Otherwise, a _comment_ would be the most appropriate way to provide a trail marker towards your answer.